# How to convert date without timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, utc

how to convert date without timezone?

data from the backend comes in the format

```
1701699255
```

I'm trying to execute code like this

```
new Date((1701699255 * 1000) - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

but it still gives me data in timezone format. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Mon Dec 04 2023 18:29:17 GMT+0000 I'm using a library for the calendar. And this library converts the data format to time zone format. Most likely I need data that would convert the time to - time zone

Comment: The data from your backend appears to be a [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - which is _always_ in terms of UTC, and JS `Date` objects can _only_ be in terms of UTC internally. They can, however, produce output in terms of local time or some other time zone, depending on what functions you use on it. Your specific approach to subtract an offset is invalid, and is called "epoch shifting". Please reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824.  Thanks.

Comment: If the intention is that a calendar component is used to select date and time without regard for time zone (or implicitly in the user's time zone), then really you should never be storing UTC values (or a Unix timestamp) at all. The better approach is to store exactly what the user picked. If the user picks 1:00 pm on Dec 4th 2023, then you should send `"2023-12-04T13:00"` to your backend, store it in exactly that manner (ie. `datetime` field in most dbs), and again send it back to the front-end exactly as `"2023-12-04T13:00"`.  This is especially important for future dates, ie. scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood your requirement; you want to convert the timestamp to a date string without timezone, for which you can use the ***[`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)*** method and then remove the timezone information from the resulting string.

```js
const timestamp = 1701699255;
const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
const dateString = date.toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
console.log(dateString); // "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" without timezone information.
```

---

Another approach is to use `getUTC*` methods in case  you want to keep the `Date` object and display it without timezone.

```js
const timestamp = 1701699255;
const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
const month = (date.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = date.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const hours = date.getUTCHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const minutes = date.getUTCMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const seconds = date.getUTCSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');

const dateString = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: wow, thanks for such quick help. You helped me a lot!

Comment: This answer is fine, but it does imply that the user meant for the UTC date and time of that particular Unix timestamp to be interpreted as actually being in local time.  That probably means the timestamp was derived incorrectly to begin with.  So having this particular sort of code is a smell that something else is wrong in the application.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint ah good point and that makes sense. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

const str = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta' });
console.log(str);